# EV3 menu tabs occasionally vanishing

Tags: ev3

When I say "EV3 menu tabs," I'm referring to **this part:**

[image: toppart]

And sometimes it disappears, just like the title says.

[image: toppartgone]

After testing the EV3, I concluded that there are certain circumstances where this occurs:

• When you make a program that will give [this error](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/3032/ev3-brick-error-symbols) while in the middle of processing (if program interferes with the display you will not be able to see it).

• When you leave the EV3 brick inactive for a few minutes.

I conclude that my EV3 screen is not defective. I can still navigate to other tabs because when I press any of the EV3 brick buttons, it shows up again. This bug has appeared only when I updated the firmware to V1.10E, and since I see that this version lacks the Brick Datalogging app, I'm not surprised that this ends up appearing too.

Has anyone else had this problem? Has any genius out there already came up with a fix for this? Or do I have to send a report to LEGO™ about it and wait for a new version?

**Edit:** Here's some code that is likely to trigger this problem.

[image: BadProgramThatWillCrash]

Comment: Reading your question I understood this issue has only appeared post recent firmware update and it seems like you treat it as a bug. We might not be able to answer this vendor specific question. Have you tried submitting a bug report?

Comment: @Alex Nope, not yet... but I guess I will.  Can you try testing that program of mine to see if you get the problem, or do you not own the EV3 brick?